# TypeScript function arrow expression returning object

Tags: typescript

I have such case:

```
interface MoverShaker {
    getStatus(): { speed: number; frequency: number; };
}

function GetMoverShaker() : MoverShaker {
    return {
        getStatus: () => { speed: 2, frequency: 3 }
    }
}
```

I am getting such error: The name 'frequency' does not exist in the current scope. Is such construction possible in TypeScript? If I am using such construction then everything is ok:

```
function GetMoverShaker(): MoverShaker {
    return {
        getStatus: () => {
             return { speed: 2, frequency: 3 }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 184):

You can add parens:

```
() => ({x:1,y:2})
```

This makes the parser understand that the { is not the beginning of a code block.

Comment: You can also do this via cast.
`() => <any>{x:1,y:1}`

Comment: I don't like casting to *any*. Actually I've also just been bitten by casting to desired output interface type, when adding a new property to the interface. As I was doing an explicit cast from a (any) object literal, VS Code did not flagged any error even if the literal was missing the new property.

Answer (score 2):

In your first statement you do not return an object.
If you want to disregard the `return` keyword in an arrow function that returns an `object` you will need to wrap the directly returned value in `()`.

Which will make your function look like this instead

```
function GetMoverShaker() : MoverShaker {
    return {
        getStatus: () => ({ speed: 2, frequency: 3 })
    }
}
```